# Cannot identify RMSE from ARIMA model

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, time-series, arima

i want to know the error result like RMSE, etc from ARIMA. i have a 45 months of data about Night-lights. i Have a ARIMA model like this

```
fitARIMA <- arima(newdata, order=c(0,0,0),seasonal = list(order = c(1,0,0), period = 12))
summary(fitARIMA)
### here is the result
Call:
arima(x = newdata, order = c(0, 0, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), period = 12))
            
Coefficients:
       sar1  intercept
      0.4770   572.1038
s.e.  0.1608    38.5140
            
sigma^2 estimated as 26880:  log likelihood = -294.88,  aic = 593.76
            
Training set error measures:
              ME RMSE MAE MPE MAPE
Training set NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN
Warning message:
In trainingaccuracy(object, test, d, D) :
test elements must be within sample
```

Anyone know why this is happened, and how to solve this proble? thank you

here is the data i used

```
         Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul
2015  467.38  441.67  579.30  600.41  793.38  576.80  741.21
2016  516.02  241.41  443.20  502.98  497.31  668.08  596.89
2017  325.89  253.30  737.37  462.75  609.31  559.05  581.16
2018  428.74  584.53  508.92  655.63  867.83 1059.98  509.34
         Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2015  634.66  582.00  661.35  249.46  482.33
2016  686.76  598.28  598.23  391.71  492.66
2017  680.36  753.18  476.41    3.12  608.01
2018  820.85  825.13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `arima` with `Arima`. The `Arima()` function from the forecast package saves additional information which is used by the `summary()` function.

Assuming your `newdata` object is of `ts` class with frequency set to 12, the following simpler code should work.

```r
fitARIMA <- Arima(newdata, order=c(0,0,0), seasonal = c(1,0,0))
summary(fitARIMA)
```

Comment: Wow, that's solve my problem. Thank you so much sir